# Ajax browser back button not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm still struggling with a the browser's history back/forward buttons when using ajax and jQuery. In order to change just a single div on the website, I'm using this function:

```
$(document).on("click",".ajaxLink",function(e){         
    var hash = jQuery(this).attr('href').split("?")[1];

    window.history.pushState("object or string", "my website", "<?php echo $path, "?"; ?>" + hash);

    $('#content').load("content.php?" + hash);
    return false; // do not follow link
});
```

When using the links it's working fine. However, on clicking the browser's back or forward button, only the address in the address bar changes but not the content. I've tried some solutions like Ben Alman's hashchange, unfortunately they didn't work for me.

To retrieve the content from content.php I'm using get requests (which look like content.php?cat=foo)

I'd be really pleased if anyone can come up with a solution!

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/howto-force-page-reload-refresh-of-previous-page-when-back-button-is-pressed

Comment: I think you should be looking at `popstate`.

Comment: popstate may lead to a solution. I've tried
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
 var hash = window.location;
 alert(hash);
});
It alerts the url so far, but as soon as I change hash to window.location.split("?")[1]; nothing happens any more. Why?

Comment: try this: `window.location.toString().split('?')[1]`

Comment: Using window.history.pushState(hash, "my website", "<?php echo $path, "?"; ?>" + hash); in the click function combined with
jQuery(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
     var hash = event.originalEvent.state;
     $('#content').load("content.php?" + hash);
    });
does the trick